# Oracle through proxy (squid proxy)

Tags: oracle, proxy, squid

Can I connect to oracle server via proxy. I have a squid proxy running and I am trying to connect to my oracle machine via the squid proxy. This is due to the fact the oracle server is not directly accessible via my machine. Is this possible? Or is there any other way accessing oracle via a different machine?

Answer (score 1):

Squid is a web proxy so, not surprisingly, it doesn't support the protocol an Oracle client uses to connect to an Oracle database.  You can't use squid as a database proxy.

[Oracle Connection Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/cman.htm) can be used as a proxy for database connections.  You can install that on a server that your client has access to and that has access to the database server and then connect to the database via Connection Manager.  Some firewalls have built-in support for proxying Oracle database connections as well.

Comment: Thank you :) I can not find a download link for connection manager alone? do i need to install full oracle to get connection manager?

Comment: @neolivz4ever - I don't believe you can download Connection Manager separately.  I expect that you need the full installer but then you can do a custom install so you're not installing everything on the proxy machine.